# Unknown activity items supplied for ActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to share videos from my app using a UIActivityViewController. Below is the code I use:

```
var url = NSURL(string: path!)!
var activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in })
```

The path points to a valid .mov file so no problems there. When I present the activity view controller I get the error: **Unknown activity items supplied** with the path to the .mov file and the sharing options only show AirDrop.

The app is running on iOS 8.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** I found out that when I save the video to camera roll. the user can share it with Photos app to any app. So there's nothing wrong with the video format I guess.

Comment: Could you show the error-message?

Comment: 2015-01-25 13:39:25.548 myApp[8850:1366084] Unknown activity items supplied: (
    "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/97D53B7E-4F17-4CE3-9D6D-2D81E36D8292/tmp/54c3b52eb86dccf971c01d72.mov"
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `init?(fileURLWithPath path: String, isDirectory isDir: Bool)` if the movie is in resource bundle.

If you use imagePicker controller to select the video, you can get the url from info dictionary using the key `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`, the corresponding delegate method is `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

Comment: I'm not using image picker as I am downloading the video from internet into the app documents directory.

Comment: Sorry, I can't exactly understand what you're suggesting. The mov is not in the resource bundle, it's in documents directory. Also I don't want to use ImagePicker to let the user choose the video because the video is already playing on the screen. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I understand what your concern, what I mean is change your code `var url = NSURL(string: path!)!` to `var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)`, I just did a test it worked for me.

Comment: Wow that worked! I tried with different apps, only it didn't work with Viber but that's not a problem :-)

Comment: How did you save your movie to the temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in })
```

Comment: The options appear with this but this treats the path as a string and shares the path of the file only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for a zip file and realised the url path I was passing was relative and not an absolute path. In other words, UIActivityViewController urls require the prefix `file:///`

I was using a relative path because the third party library Objective-Zip needs a relative path to create zip files.

**Works:**
`file:///`private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63284C22-6E22-4865-965C-3B67F58D0659/tmp/myfile.zip

**Doesn't work:**
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63284C22-6E22-4865-965C-3B67F58D0659/tmp/myfile.zip